# navigate to the implementation of a data-type or a function

Tags: eclipse, rascal

I was wondering if there was the equivalent of "Ctrl+left-click" in eclipse for java, that takes me to the implementation of a method or a data-type in Rascal. I'm finding it a little hard to sort through a list of references brought up by doing a "Ctrl+H" search everytime.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: *not yet*.

The longer answer is: we are working hard on a type checker and compiler for Rascal and those will provide the basic information for jumping to definitions, uses, and the like. As soon as that information is available we will integrate it in Eclipse.